# Я создал два множества. Скачиваю с пользователя фамилии. В x имеются Петров, Сидоров, Иванов, вводится же еще потом Петров,Петров, Иванов

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
x = set()
y = set()
for i in range(n):
    surname = input()
    x.add(surname)
    if surname not in x:
        y.add(surname)
```

Comment: Как Петрова, Петрова, ИВанова поместить в y? Туда скачиваются почему-то то же, что и в x

Comment: Множество не может хранить две одинаковые записи. Поэтому там не может сохраниться 2 Петрова.

Comment: Но туда же еще попадает сидоров, петров, в итоге два одинаковых множества, почему?

Comment: Напишите чётко, что у вас на входе, и что конкретно при данном входе должно попасть в x и в y. Из вашего кода не ясно чего вы пытались добиться.

Comment: Ввод: число, и это же число фамилий. Мне нужно однофамильцы среди этих фамилий, при помощи множеств(операций), так как большего я пока не знаю

Comment: Всё равно не понятно. `x` должен содержать уникальные фамилии, а `y` - фамилии, которые встретились 2 и более раз? Так что ли?

Comment: Да. Формат ввода
В первой строке указывается количество мужчин - сотрудников организации (N). Затем идут N строк с фамилиями этих сотрудников в произвольном порядке.

Формат вывода
Количество однофамильцев в организации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прямо-таки на множествах, то вот:

```
x = set()   # все фамилии по одному разу
y = set()   # фамилии которые встретились 2 и более раза
count = 0

n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    surname = input()
    if surname in x:
        y.add(surname)
        count += 1
    else:
        x.add(surname)

count += len(y)
print(count)
```

Т.е. в `y` собираются фамилии, если они уже встречались (и, соответственно, были до этого занесены в `x`). И заодно в переменной `count` ведётся подсчёт сколько фамилий было помещено в `y`. Но т.к. при первом обнаружении фамилии её не учитывали, то к результату надо добавить количество элементов множества `y` (как бы если бы их все учитывали при первом обнаружении).

Answer (score 0):

если как вы привели задача такая:

> Начальник кадровой службы хочет узнать, сколько мужчин-однофамильцев
> работает в организации. У него есть список фамилий, и на основании
> этого списка нужно вычислить количество фамилий, которые совпадают с
> другими. Формат ввода В первой строке указывается количество мужчин -
> сотрудников организации (N). Затем идут N строк с фамилиями этих
> сотрудников в произвольном порядке. Формат вывода Количество
> однофамильцев в организации.

вам вот это нужно что ли?

```
count = int(input())

people = []

namesakes = 0

for i in range(count):
    name = input()

    if name in people:
        namesakes += 2 if len([obj for obj in people if name in obj == name]) == 1 else 1

    people.append(name)

print(namesakes)
```

Comment: x должен содержать уникальные фамилии, а y - фамилии, которые встретились 2 и более раз? И найти пересечение множеств

Comment: Начальник кадровой службы хочет узнать, сколько мужчин-однофамильцев работает в организации. У него есть список фамилий, и на основании этого списка нужно вычислить количество фамилий, которые совпадают с другими.

Формат ввода
В первой строке указывается количество мужчин - сотрудников организации (N). Затем идут N строк с фамилиями этих сотрудников в произвольном порядке.

Формат вывода
Количество однофамильцев в организации.

Comment: ну да, приведенный код (убрал лишнее) и решает данную задачу